# How to Group While Loop "Results" of wp_query?

Tags: tags, get-posts

I have the results from a query and they're fine, I am getting post via tags. I want to sort the result in WHILE LOOP.
Here's the code

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
if ($tags) {
    $first_tag = $tags[1]->term_id;
    $args=array(
        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
        // 'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'caller_get_posts'=>1,
        'posts_per_page' =>100,
        'post_type'=>'episode',
        'orderby' => 'post_title',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ){

            $s = 0;

            while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

                $original_title = get_the_title();
                list($a, $b) = explode(' Season ', $original_title);
                $exp_count = explode(' Season ', $original_title);
                $c = substr("$b",0,2).'<br>';

                echo 'Season '.$c;
                echo get_the_title() . '<br>';

            endwhile;

        }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

Here's the Output

[image]

What I want is to sort the Season 3 and Season 4 Separately Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I will probably do something like this to make it dynamic but this have some issue with the title that must be "Season $n" in the title.

Probably better solution will be to add some custom field with the season or some custom taxonomy just to filter.

```
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ){

    $seasons = array();
    foreach($my_query->posts as $mypost) {
        preg_match('/Season (\d*)/', $mypost->post_title, $season);
        $seasons[$season[1]][] = $mypost;
    }
    // and then you could use seasons array

}
```